# SignedXml.CheckSignature() is always false

Tags: c#, xml, ssl, certificate, signedxml

I'm receiving signed XML from a third party with a certificate attached. I also have a copy of this certificate locally to verify that the serial numbers are equal, which they are, so I'm certain that the XML is signed by the same certificate that I have locally.

However SignedXml.CheckSignature() always returns false, so the verification always fails. Why is that? From what I've understood signed XML always includes a copy of the certificate it is signed by, and the parameterless method tries to validate the signature against this certificate. Shouldn't this always work?

FYI: Verifying the signature with the local certificate copy also fails in every case.

**EDIT 09th Dec 2016**

Upon further inspection I see that the signed XML has been signed using two transforms, but upon validation I can only specify one single canonicalization method. The example XML is attached below.

Could the problem be caused by the reference prefixed by cid as mentioned at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2010/08/18/creating-signatures-with-signedxml-following-ebxml-standard/? It is a fairly old article, things could have changed since then.

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/RECxml-c14n-20010315"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod>
            <ds:Reference URI="">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#envelopedsignature"></ds:Transform>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></ds:Transform>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
                    <ds:DigestValue>RJ2QdODr5ADUs9RAR9aT8NFdqds=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
            <ds:Reference URI="cid:ebxhmpayload111@example.com">
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
                    <ds:DigestValue>j1BG/SCN4Z74inL530u2SYGWKtE=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>ZRLxNWAWqxvW1d9vdtZhQ3cII02NhUk7H8ugAML0cIrP0noebUMikAOuX6fNIVTvi4kLAeb3FfQqBJD6heRWrM0lMZsA0rIHVOtH3fc6JqwUWRuiS9zzuKIx5ah8O0yU1ZkeS5b6fTJtX36+idO5KvTZc2az7fpWhPLcrfcyT4A=
    </ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>*redacted*</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
```

Code:

```
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlData);
        var signedXmlDoc = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
        var signatureNodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");
        signedXmlDoc.LoadXml((XmlElement)signatureNodeList[0]);
        var signingCertificate = new X509Certificate2(sender.SigningCertificate);
        foreach (var ex in signingCertificate.Extensions)
        {
            if (ex.Oid.Value == "2.5.29.15")
            {
                var ext = (X509KeyUsageExtension)ex;
                if (!ext.KeyUsages.HasFlag(X509KeyUsageFlags.NonRepudiation))
                    throw new CertificateException("The signing certificate does not support non-repudiation.");
            }
        }

        var transmittedCert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("X509Certificate")[0].InnerText));
        if (transmittedCert.SerialNumber != signingCertificate.SerialNumber)
            throw new CertificateException("Serial numbers do not match. The message was signed by another certificate");

        var validSignature = signedXmlDoc.CheckSignature();
```